# Script to send an alert mail once the disk space is above 90% sends disk full even when the disk isn't full, how to resolve this issue?

Tags: email, disk-usage, storage, mail-command

```
#!/bin/bash

df -m > myfile
server_ip_address=$(ip addr show $(ip route | awk '/default/ { print $5 }') | grep "inet" | head -n 1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1)

if awk '$2 > 10000 && $5 > 90' myfile ; then
    echo "Disk Full in $server_ip_address"
else
    echo "Nothing wrong with the server"
fi
```

When I execute the script, always get disk full as output?
Output of df -m looks like this:

```
Filesystem              1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root    949305 512827    436479  55% /
devtmpfs                     3811      0      3811   0% /dev
tmpfs                        3823      0      3823   0% /dev/abc
tmpfs                        3823     18      3806   1% /run
tmpfs                        3823      0      3823   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    1014    175       840  18% /boot
/dev/sda1                    1022     12      1011   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                         765      0       765   0% /run/user/2000
```

The outut of df -m differs from server to server. I am thus comparing if Size>10GB and Use%>90%. As some disk with size<10GB may not be important to be under 90% disk usage.

**Update 1:**

GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

OS is centos 7

Problem with the current code:

I need to compare from the second row to last row columns, but my current code is comparing the first rows columns, that's why I suppose it's not working. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: I get 3 flags in shellcheck. When run, it fails on the very first word: var is not a shell keyword, built-in, or external command. Please show us what you get when you execute it. Also, is it really two lines, or has it posted badly? If it runs for you but produces no output, tweak the 10G and 90% to 1G and 1% to force some output. Also state your OS info and Bash versions.

Comment: FYI, your `| grep "inet" | head -n 1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1` pipeline can be shortened to just `| awk -F'[[:space:]]+|/' '$2 == "inet" { print $3; exit}'` (this uses either whitespace or a `/` as the field separator, so the IP address is $3).  It's almost never required or useful (and certainly not efficient) to pipe grep's output into awk.  Same with piping awk into cut.  awk can do everything that both grep and cut can do, and more.  and by exiting immediately after printing the required column from the first match, `head -n 1` isn't needed either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Problem in my current code is that the output of df -H is not always in GB*

The answer here is not to use `-H`. As documented in `man df` it is intended as "human readable output" and the unit intentionally can vary.

Instead use a fixed unit: either the default KB or maybe MB (`-m`).

You may also want to read up about Nagios (Icinga). This is a monitoring tool that includes scripts to address exactly the sort of monitoring that you are addressing.

> *When I execute the script, always get disk full as output*

This is because `if awk ...` always returns true, because the `awk` always ends successfully unless it encounters an error attempting to execute its script (file not found, syntax error, etc.), or the script exits with a specific non-zero status

---

I would be inclined to consider writing the script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
myIP=$(
    ip -j route |
    jq -r '.[] | select(.dst == "default") | .gateway'
)

df=$(
    df -lm -x tmpfs |
    awk '
        NR==1 { header=$0 }
        $5+0 > 90 { if (length(header)) { print header; header="" }; print }
    '
)

if [ -n "$df" ]
then
    echo "Problems with server $myIP"
    echo
    echo "$df"
else
    echo "Disk space seems ok on $myIP"
fi
```

Comment: Don't want to be mean, but that script is beyond my level of understanding. I guess I need some readings.

Comment: @achhainsan split it up into bits. It's basically three statements. Take the first (the `ip | jq`) and see what it produces. Split that multiline command into parts, see what the first part (`ip`) does. Look up its documentation (`man ip` and `man ip-route`). Add on the second part (`jq`); how does the output get changed? Use the opportunity

Comment: jq command is not found in server (no installation privileges).

Comment: @achhainsan ask your Change Board to install it, or else install it into your home directory. Using CB would be the better solution in a professional environment, but may take a little longer to deliver